# Gunicorn Connection in Use: ('0.0.0.0', 5000)

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn, foreman

I installed redis this afternoon and it caused a few errors, so I uninstalled it but this error is persisting when I launch the app with `foreman start`. Any ideas on a fix?

```
foreman start
22:46:26 web.1  | started with pid 1727
22:46:26 web.1  | 2013-05-25 22:46:26 [1727] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.17.4
22:46:26 web.1  | 2013-05-25 22:46:26 [1727] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 5000)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check your processes. You may have had an unclean exit, leaving a zombie'd process behind that's still running.

Comment: I ran `ps -ax` but can't identify which process is causing the problem. Any tips on what to look for?

Comment: I killed the gunicorn processes and everything seems to be working again.

Comment: netstat -tulpn | grep 5000 helps

Answer (score 50):

Just type

```
sudo fuser -k 5000/tcp
```

.This will kill all process associated with port 5000

Answer (score 15):

This should do the trick for you:

`kill -9 $(lsof -i:5000 -t) 2> /dev/null`

where 5000 is the port you want to kill

Comment: Works on Mac as well

Answer (score 10):

I know that if you're running MacOS, you may see "ControlCe" listed as the process. You can kill it, but it will just restart. After some searching, I found that the control center uses 5000 to listen for Airplay Receiver requests. You can disable this by System Preferences>Sharing>Airplay Receiver.

Answer (score 7):

After some searching on the web, it looks like the following command is the best to use. This kills all of the processes running on port 5000 and appeared to work for me:

```
kill `lsof -i :5000`
```

[Source (although a bit more shady than I prefer)](http://www.itgo.me/a/1898019484748814608/heroku-local-web-doesnt-work-because-of-gunicorn-connection-in-use)

Answer (score 3):

Find the orphaned process:

```
ps -ax |grep gunicorn

11111 ?? 0:03.44 /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -b :5000 main:app
```

Locate the Process ID (the number in the first column of the results)

```
kill 11111
```

*Replace 11111 with the Process ID*